# Google Calendar client javascript missing refresh token

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, refresh-token

I am trying to implement Google Calendar into our web project. After searching and trying almost all the tricks in my bag, I could not get the refresh token after user gives consent to access the Calendar. I want to take user's calendar access at my front end(access token and refresh token) and provide it the backend(python) for refreshing the access token later.
After trying several solutions available, I am using this one -
In html -

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

In javascript on button click -

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
         client_id: xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com,
         client_secret: 'XYZ',
         scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", 
         immediate: false,
         response_type: 'code token',
         access_type:'offline', 
         prompt:'consent'
}, handleAuthResult);
```

From this I am able to get the following response -

```
    {
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "XXX",
  "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "login_hint": "XXX",
  "expires_in": "3559",
  "id_token": "XXX",
  "session_state": null,
  "expires_at": "1597689877",
  "code": "4/3XXXXX",
  "status": {
    "signed_in": true,
    "method": "PROMPT",
    "google_logged_in": true
  },
  "g-oauth-window": null,
  "client_id": "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "cookie_policy": "single_host_origin",
  "response_type": "code token",
  "authuser": "2",
  "issued_at": "1597686278"
}
```

But still no sign of a refresh token, I event tried to Exchange code for access token and ID token by this api -

```
let request_params = JSON.stringify({
        code: '4/3XXXXX',
        client_id: 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        client_secret: 'XXX',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: request_params,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: (res) => {
            console.log(res, 'tokens')
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log('An error occurred', error)
        }
    });
```

But this also is giving an invalid grant_type error.
Any help is much approciated.
Also please let me know if there is any alternative where I can directly redirect using my server to get the auth instead of javascript.

Comment: Client side authorization does not return a refresh token that would be a security nightmare.  Use a server sided language.

Comment: Yes that's what I had in mind before and tried to do it by using the python sdk for google calendar, but in that credentials are obtained by running a local server which I am avoiding as it will only help me on the localhost. Any suggestions of how to do it without running the localserver?

Comment: Request access of the user when ever the access token expires will be your only option if you dont want to run a server.   How are you hosting this if you dont have a server to host it on'?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with the help of OAuth2WebServerFlow in python.
This was the process I followed -

1. Create a flow instance eg -

`flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='XXX', client_secret='XXX', scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', redirect_uri='your_redirect_url', access_type='offline', prompt='consent')`

2. Redirect to authorization url obtained by - `auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()`
3. After authentication, user gets redirected to the redirect_url provided by you along with a **code** as paramater.
4. Pass this code to the backend to obtain the access and refresh tokens using - `credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)`. Here flow would be the same flow instance generated using step 1 and credentials would have the tokens.

Note- Google doesn't provide tokens and step2_exchange generates an invalid grant error if you already have generated a valid refresh token and try to give access again.